# Add a gradient to a layer-list

Tags: android

How can I add a gradient shadow from the right and left of the background?

The following `layer-list` only adds black border from the right and left of the background, and not a gradient border.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <gradient
                android:angle="0"
                android:centerColor="#ffffff"
                android:endColor="#000000"
                android:startColor="#000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:left="2dp"
        android:right="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@color/blue" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

I am trying to add a **black shadow from the right and left** of the background.

Comment: It could be more helpful if the one who down voted my question left a comment as well.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not very sure what you want, a gradient background or a gradient border? this will give you a gradient black shadow background

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <gradient
        android:angle="0"
        android:centerColor="#ffffff"
        android:endColor="#000000"
        android:startColor="#000000" />

</shape>
```

Comment: you want your background to be blue and a gradient border?

Comment: I think you can divide your layout into three part, the left shadow , the cener background and the right shadow, Then put different shapes for their different backgrounds

Comment: you can not make it in a layer-list file because each layer is in the center and the android:left/right/top/bottom is the distace from the content to each border